# If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ then is bounded above in $[a,b]$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, alternative-proof

If $∀ϵ>0:∃δ>0:|x−a|δ<⟹|f(x)−F(a)|<E$

this implies continuity, we always say that for all $E$ we can find a delta.
But for all delta we can find a Epsilon right? (this seems okay for me,even i'm not finding such affirmation)
if is true what I said, given an interval $[a,b]$ catch $*xo*= \frac{a+b}{2}$
we have now $a------(a+b)/2-------b$
now since $*xo*$ E $[a,b]$ the definition of continuity fits,so if I choose delta= a-xo, i would stay in the closed interval and in all points this would be bounded for a $E$.

I bet this is wrong, but where i can find.

Comment: See [this article](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/~john/analysis/Lectures/L21.html)

Comment: Im gonna,thank u too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But for all delta we can find a Epsilon right? (this seems okay for me,even im not finding such affirmation)

This is the weak step of your proof. It is not generally true that
$$\forall x \exists y : P(x, y) \implies \forall y \exists x : P(x, y)$$

For a specific counterexample regarding continuity, consider the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$. This function is continuous at $a = 1$, and yet for $\delta = 1$ there is no  $\varepsilon$ such that $|x-1| < 1 \implies |f(x)-1| < \varepsilon$

(Note that in this counterexample the value of $\delta$ was specifically chosen to exploit a discontinuity of $f$ at $x = 0$. If you restrict the values of $\delta$ to ones where $f$ is continuous at the interval $[a-\delta, a+\delta]$, then it is true that for all $\delta$ you can find an $\varepsilon$, as it is indeed a theorem that continuous functions on closed intervals are bounded. But you can't use this fact while proving the theorem, as it would be circular reasoning)

Comment: i was trying thinking in a counterexample,this fits on what i was searching thank u. If i say catch a delta such that doesnt extend over the limit [a,b] then for all delta with this propertie exist an E?

Comment: I've edited the post improving the explaination and addressing that question. Yes, it is true, and it is in fact equivalent to the theorem you are trying to prove.

Comment: Yeah,i was thinking this so, if im saying that for all delta such that p-delta and p+delta is in the closed interval im assuming what i want to prove,  even not totally clearly when i assume this, You've helped a lot. So clearly man